# How to get a Doctrine 2 result as an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine

I want to get the results in array for this code:

```
 $person = $em->find('Person', 2);
```

I am using doctrine 2.  I want the above result in array form. .

PHP version 5.4

Comment: Its an object oriented tool, get used to objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution :

```
$person = $em->find('Person', 2);
$personx = json_decode(json_encode((array)$person), true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($personx);
echo '<pre>';
```

It is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to write method in your Repository class or create query builder inline (but it is not recommended).

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;


...


$qb = $em->getRepository(Person::class)->createQueryBuilder('p');
$qb
   ->andWhere('p.id = :id')
   ->setParameter('id', $id)
;

$person = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Replace

```
$qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
```

by

```
$qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
```

if you need to get only one element.

Comment: above code returning this error : Warning: include_once(Query.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 134

Comment: @Ashfaq You have to import `Query` class. Check example above I have added `use Doctrine\ORM\Query;`.

Comment: Now, I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException in D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrine2\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php:774  after change $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)

Answer (score 0):

As $person may be object with circular references, it can not be converted to array directly, but you can use serializing, like it described here
[Symfony Serialize doctrine entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069959/symfony-serialize-doctrine-entity)

Or you can do it manually:

```
$person_array = ['name' => $person->getName(), 'id' => $person->getId()];
```